# Lock Screen - Some of these settings are hidden or managed by your organization

Tags: windows-10, lock-screen

I have this message on the lock screen screen. I've tried many way to fix it:

- I do not have the NoLockScreen key
- Allow Telemetry is at full
- Disabled my antivirus
- tried O&O ShutUp10 software
- I only have 2 settings Enabled under gpedit\Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\All Settings. These are Allow Telemetry and Require use of specific security layer for remote (RDP) connection

I'm running Windows 10 Education version 1903

[image]

Comment: Who owns the Windows 10 License? You or the School?

Comment: Me only, there is no organization

Comment: Make a new, test Windows User Profile (Account). Make this Account a member of the Administrator's Group. Sign out, sign in as the new user. Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.  Run: dism.exe /online /cleanup-image  /restorehealth  . Follow this with SFC /SCANNOW.  Restart and try BOTH users. Is the message in both, neither, or one user?

Comment: Did it. Both session show message.

Comment: At least you know the error is not profile related. You could try a Windows 10 Repair Install to see if this fixes the issue. Use the second option in the link below and use the option to Keep Everything. It is easy to do but takes about an hour and a half to run. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Comment: Are you running the Insiders Preview of Windows 10?

Comment: No, this is not an Insider Preview